# Android dynamically created check box options pre checked?

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm making an app in which i need to pre checked a particular or more than one options of dynamically created checkboxes. Till now I'm able to create and get the id's of dynamically created checkboxes and store it in arraylist. My questions is how to use the values of arraylist eg:[1,2] and prechecked the options 1 and 2 of checkbox

Here is my code:

```
   private void addCheckButtons() {

   public static ArrayList<String> selchkboxlist=new ArrayList<String>();
   String chk,isa;

   String options[] = { op1, op2, op3, op4,op5 };

   for (int i = 0; i <totalchoice; i++) {
   checkedTextView=new CheckBox(this);
   checkedTextView.setText("");
   checkedTextView.setId(i);
   checkedTextView.setText(options[i]);
   checkedTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

   checkedTextView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
     { 
         public void onClick(View v) 
         { 
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 

        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            chk = Integer.toString(v.getId()+1);

                selchkboxlist.add(chk);

        } 
       else if (!((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
            chk = Integer.toString(v.getId()+1);
             selchkboxlist.remove(chk);
             System.out.println("RemoveCHECK="+selchkboxlist);
            }

        isa=String.valueOf(selchkboxlist);
        String regex = "\\[|\\]";
        isa=isa.replaceAll(regex, "");

        }
 });

   rc.addView(checkedTextView); 
    }   
}}
```

Comment: explanation in detail??

Comment: I want to check the particular option of checkbox which i previously attempted

Comment: i'm making a quiz app in which there are next and previous button and on prev button i want already checked option which were i selected.

Comment: i think it will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776623/how-to-select-multiple-radiobuttons-in-listview-and-arranging-in-arraylist-using/27779264#27779264

Comment: i want working of the checkboxes, because i have done working related to radio buttons, but there is problem related to checkboxes.

Comment: is your quize app consist of multiple answer i mean for each question it should be one answer or multiple?

Comment: i need both the radio buttons and checkboxes in my app, because it may be contain one answer or multiple answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69170/discussion-between-komal-gundavarapu-and-aparana).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [setChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html#setChecked%28boolean%29) method. That allows you to change the checked state of your `Widget`.

[Edit] Here's something I came up with (no warranties, I didn't compile or test  test it!)

```
private void addCheckButtons() {

// This must be prepopulated with checked items. Also, is static the right storage class?
public static Set<Integer> selchkboxlist = new Set<Integer>();

String options[] = { op1, op2, op3, op4,op5 };
for (int i = 0; i <totalchoice; i++) {
    checkedTextView=new CheckBox(this);
    checkedTextView.setText("");
    checkedTextView.setId(i);
    checkedTextView.setText(options[i]);
    checkedTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    checkedTextView.setChecked(selchkboxlist.contains(i));

    checkedTextView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v; 

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                selchkboxlist.add(i);
            } 
            else{
                selchkboxlist.remove(i);
                System.out.println("RemoveCHECK="+selchkboxlist);
            }
        }
    });

    rc.addView(checkedTextView); 
}   
}}
```

Comment: i already used the setchecked() method but it checked all the checkboxes, but i want to checked only the already answered checkboxes value.. please help me.

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff that's unusual and unnecessarily complex in your code. However, the simple answer is to have only call setChecked() if (checkedTextView.contains(chk). Call this along with the other checkedTextView() initialization code and not in the click handler.

Comment: can you help me with updation in my code? related to your answer. as I am beginner , so help me if u can.

Comment: I won't write your code for you, but I can suggest a few things: 1. remove 'isa' and related code as it's not used. 2. Either store the id in selchkboxlist (using ArrayList<Integer>()), or save the ID string in the view by using v.setTag(chk) and chk = (String)v.getTag(); 3. If you keep selchkboxlist as a String collection, then you should probably use a set collection instead of a list (it will be faster).

Comment: ok.. suggest that how can we change our code to perform efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will work(i am maintaning the states in one arrayList)

```
ArrayList<MyQuestionBean> mList=new ArrayList<MyQuestionBean>();
```

In the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private ArrayList<MyQuestionBean> mQuestionsList;
private int current_questionID = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.questionlayoutid);
    mQuestionsList = getQuestionsList();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showCurrentQuestion(current_questionID);
}

private void showCurrentQuestion(final int qustionID) {
    current_questionID = qustionID;
    // for question number
    final MyQuestionBean mMyQuestionBean = mQuestionsList.get(qustionID);
    Log.v(TAG, mMyQuestionBean + "");

    TextView mQuestionNo = new TextView(this);
    mQuestionNo.setText(mMyQuestionBean.getQuestion_id() + "");
    mQuestionNo.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    mQuestionNo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    // for question
    TextView mQuestion = new TextView(this);
    mQuestion.setText(mMyQuestionBean.getQuestion_name());
    mQuestion.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    mQuestion.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    // adding question and answer
    mLayout.addView(mQuestionNo);
    mLayout.addView(mQuestion);
    // create the check box as per the number of options in
    String[] options_answers = mMyQuestionBean.getOptions_answers();
    ArrayList<CheckBox> mBoxs = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    for (int i = 0; i < options_answers.length; i++) {
        CheckBox mCheckBx = new CheckBox(this);
        mCheckBx.setText(options_answers[i]);
        mCheckBx.setId(i);
        mCheckBx.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        mLayout.addView(mCheckBx);
        mBoxs.add(mCheckBx);
        mCheckBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    if (mMyQuestionBean.isAnswered()) {
                        String mQuestion_result = mMyQuestionBean.getQuestion_result();
                        mQuestion_result = mQuestion_result + buttonView.getId();
                        mMyQuestionBean.setQuestion_result(mQuestion_result);
                    } else {
                        mMyQuestionBean.setQuestion_result(buttonView.getId() + "");
                        mMyQuestionBean.setAnswered(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mBoxs.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox checkBox = mBoxs.get(i);
        if (mMyQuestionBean.getQuestion_result().contains(i + "")) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

}

public void nextQuestion(View v) {
    int temp = current_questionID + 1;
    if (temp < mQuestionsList.size()) {
        mLayout.removeAllViews();
        showCurrentQuestion(temp);
    }

}

public void previousQuestion(View v) {
    int temp = current_questionID - 1;
    if (temp >= 0) {
        mLayout.removeAllViews();
        showCurrentQuestion(temp);
    }
}

private MyQuestionBean getQuestion(int questionNumber, String questionName, String[] option_answers) {
    // By default isAnswered is false and question_result is empty("")
    MyQuestionBean mBean = new MyQuestionBean();
    mBean.setQuestion_id(questionNumber);
    mBean.setQuestion_name(questionName);
    mBean.setOptions_answers(option_answers);
    mBean.setAnswered(false);
    mBean.setQuestion_result("");
    return mBean;
}

private ArrayList<MyQuestionBean> getQuestionsList() {
    ArrayList<MyQuestionBean> myQuestionBeans = new ArrayList<MyQuestionBean>();
    MyQuestionBean question1 = getQuestion(1, "what is your favorite color", new String[] { "red", "green", "blue" });
    MyQuestionBean question2 = getQuestion(2, "what is your favorite hero", new String[] { "ram", "ajith", "komal", "chandu" });
    MyQuestionBean question3 = getQuestion(3, "what is your favorite place", new String[] { "hyd", "banguluru" });
    myQuestionBeans.add(question1);
    myQuestionBeans.add(question2);
    myQuestionBeans.add(question3);
    return myQuestionBeans;
}
}
```

In MyQuestionBean.java

```
public class MyQuestionBean {
private String question_name;
private int question_id;
private String[] options_answers;
private boolean isAnswered;
private String question_result;

public String[] getOptions_answers() {
    return options_answers;
}

public void setOptions_answers(String[] options_answers) {
    this.options_answers = options_answers;
}

public int getQuestion_id() {
    return question_id;
}

public void setQuestion_id(int question_id) {
    this.question_id = question_id;
}

public boolean isAnswered() {
    return isAnswered;
}

public void setAnswered(boolean isAnswered) {
    this.isAnswered = isAnswered;
}

public String getQuestion_result() {
    return question_result;
}

public void setQuestion_result(String question_result) {
    this.question_result = question_result;
}

public String getQuestion_name() {
    return question_name;
}

public void setQuestion_name(String question_name) {
    this.question_name = question_name;
}

public MyQuestionBean() {
    super();
}

}
```

In activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/questionlayoutid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextbttnid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="nextQuestion"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="nextbttn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previousbttnid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="previousQuestion"
    android:text="prevbttn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```